# Local notification not firing if repeat is set to daily

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, swift3

I've been facing a very strange error when trying to schedule a notification. The user provides the hour and minute when they want to have their local notification, and they can choose if they want it to be scheduled daily weekly or monthly.

However, I have run into a very weird problem. This is my code:

```
 func enableLocalNotifications() {


    notificationsSwitch.isOn = true
    notificationsOn = true

    //first cancel all current local notifications
    UIApplication.shared.cancelAllLocalNotifications()

    //create new one according to input

    let calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
    var fireComponents=calendar.dateComponents([.day, .month, .year], from:NSDate() as Date)

    fireComponents.hour = notificationHour
    fireComponents.minute = notificationMinute
    fireComponents.second = 00


    fireComponents.calendar = calendar

    let notification = UILocalNotification()
    notification.timeZone = NSTimeZone.local
    notification.alertBody = notificationDescription
    notification.alertTitle = "Reminder"
    notification.fireDate = fireComponents.date


    notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName

    switch notificationRepeat {
        case "Daily":
            notification.repeatInterval = NSCalendar.Unit.minute
        case "Weekly":
            notification.repeatInterval = NSCalendar.Unit.weekOfYear
        case "Monthly":
            notification.repeatInterval = NSCalendar.Unit.month
        default:
            break
    }

    UserDefaults.standard.setValue(notificationRepeat, forKey: "notificationRepeat")
    UserDefaults.standard.setValue(notificationDescription, forKey: "notificationDescription")
    UserDefaults.standard.setValue(notificationHour, forKey: "notificationHour")
    UserDefaults.standard.setValue(notificationMinute, forKey: "notificationMinute")
    UserDefaults.standard.setValue(true, forKey: "notificationSet")


}
```

}

The funny thing is, if I for example want to create a "daily" notification at 12:00, and at the moment it is 11:59, it just won't fire the notification at 12:00, actually it fires nothing at all. However, I have noticed, if I change the repeatInterval to NSCalendar.Unit.minute, then suddenly, if I schedule a notification for 12:00, and it's 11:59, I really receive it at 12:00.

Is there any fix for my bug?

Answer (score 0):

Double check whether the date you are setting to **notification.fireDate** is correct or not. Sometimes due to not setting proper timezones the date and time changes and it won't come at your expecting time.

Comment: Hi, sadly that wasn't the problem, but I figured it out shortly afterwards. I had been inside the application and was waiting for my local notifications to come. However, as soon as i closes the app / let it run in the background, i got all local notifications at the correct time. However, do you know how I can recognize if a local notification has been fired when the user is inside  the application?